# Is the X bar theory applicable to any natural language other than English?

Tags: x-bar-theory

Is Chomsky's X bar theory applicable to any natural language other than English? Or is it applicable to English only or to only a subset of natural languages including English?

### EDIT

I think that the X-bar theory in its default version describes the English language. If so, I wonder if there have been any efforts of either Chomsky himself or some other linguists to assign a different version with a set of different rules to another language than English, such as French, German, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc.

Comment: It's certainly applicable to more than one language, as long as you can find evidence to motivate its use (i.e. evidence that there is an intermediate level of constituency between the XP and the X head).

Comment: @WavesWashSands I wouldn't say that there must be evidence for the use of an intermediate X' level for a grammar to follow X bar assumptions. Having something like an X (head) level  and an XP (phrase) level already is part of an X-bar motivated theory, and whether you ever encounter the need of a X1 level instance is not so much an issue if you either still include the additonal layer (branching unary into *XP - X' - X - word*) or decide to omit redunant bar levels graphically.

Comment: @lemontree Do you mean that if the analysis includes endocentric constituents, then we're already using X-bar theory? If so, I think that's slightly strange - Chomsky (1957) also has endocentric constituents, but we wouldn't say he was using X-bar then...

Comment: No one in their right mind likes X-bar!

Comment: Chomsky's whole mission was to describe how the human language faculty works, and therefore every human language. So of course it was his intention that X-bar theory works for every language. Whether it's successful is another question.

Comment: @curiousdannii But X-bar doesn't 'belong' to Chomsky. There are linguists who use it without sharing Chomsky's assumptions, and who do not necessarily advocate shoehorning non-English languages without intermediate constituents (and constructions without intermediate constructions in English) into the X-bar schema. So I think it's preferable to approach the OP's question from a more neutral perspective.

Comment: @Waves Yeah I know but the OP called it "Chomsky's X bar theory", and I was just following them to focus on Chomsky. Perhaps they mean Chomsky's specific uses of the theory, or maybe they just don't know of others. In any case, it is to be expected that most linguists want reliable cross-linguistic models and theories!

Comment: I don't know the history of X bar theory, but I know it's definitely not true that the default language is English!

Comment: @curiousdannii Oops - didn't see that, sorry! I've seen the question before and didn't re-read it - my mistake. I think when the OP said the default version described the English language, I think he means that a lot of the early work in X-bar focused on English, and used mainly English evidence for motivating bar-levels or phrases. (And indeed, I think most introductions to syntax use English to introduce X-bar.) Of course that is no longer true now, as phrases exist (e.g. KP) which are clearly not motivated by English.

Comment: I think most of Chomsky's works are dubious if you try to apply them to languages drastically different to Indo-European languages. In fact we had a class this semester and there were already several problems when trying to apply them to German, and I thought it would definitely be very hard to apply it to Chinese. X-bar is a fairly general term that is used in several types of syntax theories such as GB, GPSG, LFG, and HPSG, but AFAIK most of those syntax theories have problems when it comes to non-Indo-European languages. In fact Chomsky himself abandoned X bar when he moved to minimalist.

Comment: @JIXiang I can't speak for GPSG/HPSG, but LFG doesn't have problems when it comes to non-IE languages; it simply doesn't use X-bar when it's not useful.

Answer (score 2):

The general X bar scheme is, although heavily motivated by English - or at least Indo-European languages - thought to be applicable to any natural language.
How well that works depends highly on what other restrictions you impose on your phrase structure (strict right/left linear and/or binary branching for example makes a lot of things not possible), but the basics of X bar theory are not more than a handful of rules determining how consitutent trees are built up, without making any claims about, e.g., available syntactic categories, morphological features or c-command relations.
So, yes, basic X bar scheme is definitely applicable and practically applied to languages other than English.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give some examples if you assert it is definitely applicable to languages other than English. We had a syntax class last semester and there were already problems with German, not to mention when I think in Chinese. I think the point is that "X bar theory" barely exists in isolation but is often used with various syntax theories, which make many assumptions and thus make them quite unsuitable to some non-Indo-European languages. And then if you say you want to ditch those assumptions, then X bar theory on its own can't really be used as a syntax theory anyways.